# Preventing a website from redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

Some websites, when launched for the first time (in a session), redirect to advertisements for brief time. For example, http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/ (homepage) sends its users to http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/defaultinterstitial.cms (advertisement) for a few seconds. However, on refreshing the homepage later, or upon opening the homepage again, the website does not redirect.

Can this redirect be prevented through some javascript bookmark/cookie? How do I find out?

Comment: whoever thinks that this is worth closing or downvoting, please leave a comment here. Don't just run away.

Comment: disable javascript?

Comment: disabling might cause other problems. I don't want to impact the whole website or other websites.

Comment: exactly, I don't think there is a possible way to disable one site w/o affecting all other sites as well. By the sounds of it, you want a solution that works on all sites that redirect you but without the benefit of prior knowledge of which sites these are and the technology/methods behind it.  - making this question too generic - Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve the question

Answer (score 0):

It most likely stores something in local storage or a cookie.  Local/Session Storage you could spoof.  Cookie may be more difficult.  If the cookie exists maybe you will luck out and see that it passes a URL parameter or something you can copy.  It didn't redirect for me to test it.  You could use an ad blocker or firewall rule and block the URL.  If a different IP you could make a host file entry to prevent going there.  It may need redirected back though,  so you may go nowhere and then it won't go back.